# Currying syntax clarification - how to work through an example of currying?

Tags: notation, computer-science, computability

I understand currying from a computer science background, so I'm happy explaining currying with a before and after example in specific languages, eg, in Java

```
public static Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Integer>> add() {
    return x -> y -> x + y;
}
```

is the curried form of

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

or even

`λa.(λb. + a b)` as the curried form of `λab.+ a b` in lambda calculus

but I'm **not sure how to represent it with just [mathematics syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)**, would it be like this?

Give some function `f`,

$$f(a, b) = a + b$$

The curried version would be this?

$$f(a) \rightarrow f(b) \rightarrow a + b$$

or this?

$$f(a) \Rightarrow f(b) \Rightarrow a + b$$

or even this?

$$f(a) \rightarrow f(b) = a + b$$

As you can see, I'm floundering with the "f(a) returns a function f(b)" part. I'm not sure if "material implication" or "map" are even suitable!

Comment: You could do something along these lines. Does identifying the following functions match your idea? $f(x,y)=x+y$, $f=((x,y)\mapsto x+y)$, $f=(x\mapsto(y\mapsto x+y))$. This is more in the spirit of mathematical function notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to say that lambda calculus certainly also is a form of mathematical notation. But onwards to your question.

When we talk about functions, we usually specify two things: the domain and codomain of the function, and what the function actually does. So in this case, your function would have domain $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and codomain $\mathbb{Z}$, so we would write
$$f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}.$$
To curry this, we want to make sure that each domain only has one dimension, so that we can write
$$curry(f):\mathbb{Z} \to (\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}).$$
So this is the correct context to use the $\to$-notation.

However, we of course also want to give a description of what the curried function actually does, which is more along the lines of what you have tried to do in your question. So we start with a function
$$f(a,b) = a + b,$$
and we make a new function
$$g(a) = (b \mapsto f(a,b))$$
where the notation $b \mapsto f(a,b)$ means that $b$ is mapped to $f(a,b)$. With regards to computer science, you can think of the notation $x \mapsto y$ as an anonymous function instead of writing $f(x) = y$. Note also that, technically, we make a *new* function for each value of $b$, so if we were pedantic mathematicians, we would write
$$g_b(a) = (b \mapsto (f(a,b))$$
to make explicit that the function $g$ depends on our choice of $b$.

As a last comment, the symbol $\implies$ for implication is not applicable in this case.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I just need to work out if I can explain the notation (as I'm doing a presentation!)

Comment: @Toby if you're doing a presentation and you're familiar with lambda calculus notation, then you may as well use that in your presentation instead. When talking about currying, this is the usual formalism used to express the idea. Also, if you like the answer you can accept it.

Comment: Would it make sense / still be accurate if I wrote $$g(a) = (b \mapsto (f(a,b))$$ as $$g(a) = (b \mapsto a + b))$$?

Comment: @Toby yes, because $f(a,b) = a+ b$.

Comment: I have also encountered the notation $g(a)(b)$ for the curried $f(a, b)$. It might look kinda silly, but it's straightforward, as $g(a)$ is itself a function taking $b$ as input.